# How to use the Mean Value Theorem or Rolle's in this word problem.

Tags: calculus

I'm a bit stuck on how to solve this word problem:

1. Two runners start a race at the same time and finish in a tie. Prove that at some time during the race they have the same speed. [Hint: Consider $f(t) = g(t) - h(t)$ where g and h are the position functions of the two runners.]

I know this is the mean value theorum:

[image]

And this is Rolle's:

[image]

Here's how I started:

Assuming g(t) and h(t) are the position functions of the runners, then we know that at 2 points (the beginning and the end of the race), they are equal.

So $f(t)$ is like the difference between the two position functions. It is equal to 0 at the start and at the end.

Where do I go from here?

when I write this question out, this seems more like an application of Rolle's theorem... instead of Mean Value theorem right?

Like $f(t) = 0$ at the beginning and end
$f(t)$ is differentiable and continuous.
So there is a number c where that $f'(c) = 0$ meaning the two runners have the same speed at some point.

How do I prove this though? Is this a proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it **is** a proof. You are correct, this is Rolle's Theorem, which is special case of Mean Value Theorem.

So, your proof is fine.

Comment: Anything else I could do? Or is this fine as is?

Comment: @Jwan It's fine, btw you can add a bracket `(By Rolle's Theorem)` when you write the step $g'(c)=h'(c)$ to specify the reason that how you concluded.

Comment: Rolle's theorem is actually equivalent to the mean value theorem.

Comment: Yes, all we need is to just rotate the axes @Jannik. But I am saying special case, it's easy to see it that way.